# Equivalence of norms in finite-dimensional spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Assume we have a separable, reflexive Banach space $X$ such that $\{e_{i}\}$ is a basis.

Let $X_{n} = \text{span}\{e_{1},\ldots,e_{n}\}$ be finite-dimensional subspaces where we define members $u_{n} \in X_{n}$
by $u_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{k}^{n}e_{k}$ where $c^{n} = (c^{n}_{1},...,c^{n}_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. What I want to know is if it is true that for all $R_{o} > 0$
there exists a $S \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $c^{n} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $|c^{n}|=S$(using the usual norm in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$) it follows that
$\Vert u_{n} \Vert_{X} = R_{o}$(using the norm of $X_{n}$)? (the reals are denoted as $\mathbb{R}$)

I am trying to use this idea in a larger proof.
The proof that I am referring to is the Browder and Minty Theorem. It uses the following Lemma:

[image]

The First step of the proof of the Theorem is as follows:
[image]

The part of the proof of the Theorem I don't follow is how you can apply Lemma 1.11 directly by considering '$c^{n} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $\Vert u_{n} \Vert_{X} = R_{o}$' instead of $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $|x| = R$ as is the requirement of the Lemma 1.11. I thought my idea above would resolve this.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something here, but I think this gives you a counter example: Suppose that $X_n = X = \Bbb{R}^2$ endowed with the Euclidean norm, $e_1 = (1,1)$, and $e_2 = (0,1)$. Then for any $S > 0$, $\| Se_1 \| = \sqrt{2}S$ and $\|S e_2 \| = S$.

Comment: @Tom I don't quite see how this is a counter-example. Maybe you could label it in line with my notation?

Comment: It seems that you want $\Vert u_{n} \Vert_{X}=f(|c^{n}|)$ for some function $f$. That is certainly false: the norm from $X$ may restrict to $\max_k|c_k^{n}|$ on $X_n$, and that is certainly not a function of $|c^{n}|$ since you can have vectors with the same Euclidean length but different max coordinates.

Comment: @Conifold Yes I think that is a good way stating what I was looking for. Could you see the updated question, I have added attachments which show the Lemma and Theorem that inspired the question. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider the idea. Nothing like this is true in general. A few remarks:

1. The complicated condition $\forall R_0\ \exists S$ is redundant. Norms respect the scaling of vectors. (If you know which vectors have norm $1$, you know everything about the norm.) So, if the  condition $\forall R_0\ \exists S$ holds, you can state is more simply: there is $k>0$ such that $\|u_n\|_X = k\, |c^n|$.
2. The *equivalence of two norms* (denoted $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|_*$) is usually understood as the existence of $C$ such that for every vector $v$, $\|x\|\le C\|x\|_*$ and $\|x\|_*\le C\|x\|$. This is substantially weaker than 1.
3. But even the condition stated in item 2 will fail, unless your $X$ is a Hilbert space in disguise. Take $\ell_p$ for $p\ne 2$, with the standard basis. The $\ell_p$ norm of $(1,1,\dots,1)\in X^n$   is $n^{1/p}$, while the Euclidean norm is $n^{1/2}$. Since $n$ can be arbitrarily large, the ratio of two norms is not controlled as in item 2.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated the question to show the Browder and Minty Theorem that inspired the question. Can you see how to resolve this problem?